# writing a function that takes int n and returns the sum of odd less than n

Tags: java, algorithm, sum

Here is my code

```
public static int sumOfOddLessThan(int n)
{
    int iResult = 0;
    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0 && i % 2 != 0; i--)
    {
        iResult = iResult + i;
    }
    return iResult;
}
```

It does not work correctly, I dunno why :\

It should return 4 when I enter 5 but it returns 0

Comment: Did you try stepping through your program in a debugger?

Comment: shortcut: (n + (n % 2)) * (n + (n % 2)) / 4

Comment: @Jesse - since it's less than, not less than or equal to, whouldn't you need (n - (n % 2)) instead? By your logic, f(9) = 25, when it should be 16.

Comment: @glowcoder -- oops, i misread the question! thought it said <=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting the condition `i % 2 != 0` in the for loop instead of an `if` inside of the loop, hence if it's not met even once it breaks out of the entire loop.

Your code should look like this:

```
public static int sumOfOddLessThan(int n)
{
    int iResult = 0;
    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(i % 2 != 0) {
            iResult = iResult + i;
        }
    }
    return iResult;
}
```

Then again you don't even need a loop, you can evaluate it directly by getting the number of odd numbers lower than `N` and squaring that.

Comment: +1 for optimizing the loop out. `int sumOdds(int n) { if(n%2 == 1) n--; return (n/2)*(n/2); }` Although since this is homework, he'll have to do the math behind it to show why it works that way.

Comment: @glowcoder: Yes, I did not post the algorithm as some other answer already has it. Note: I don't think you need to do the `n--` thing as `int` is rounded down anyway when divided.

Comment: the `--` is to conform to the `<` instead of `<=` requirement. Without the `n--` in there, `f(9) = 25` when it should be `f(9) = 16`.

Comment: @Glowcoder: for an `int`, `9 / 2 == 4` so it should still work, the `n--` just makes it `8 / 2` which is still `4`.

Comment: my mistake. When I did it by hand, I found an error. When I code it up using both versions (as well as your version in the code as a comparison) I find it to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Your conditional in the for loop reads:

`i is greater than 0 and i is not even`.

When you call the method with 5 as argument, the first value of i will be 4, which is even and therefore the loop does not get evaluated.

```
for(i = n-1; i > 0; i++) {
    if(i%2==0) {
        iResult += i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why. However, if this is homework I *strongly* encourage you to discover this with the debugger. Being able to step through your code and determine this on your own is a critical skill.

Comment: This kind of thing is normally quite hard for a beginner to detect with a debugger as stepping over the line just skips the for loop. But yes, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

you should modify the forumla used for adding the series, all you gotta do is to modify it

**earlier**

```
int i = (n+1)/2;
return (i*i)
```

**modified**

```
int i = n/2;
return (i*i);
```

**TEST**
input 1:
return 0;

input 2:
return 1;

input 3:
return 1;

input 4:
return 4;

input 5:
return 4;

input 6:
return 9;

and so on ..

Comment: Great! but why it doesn't work correctly when I replace (i*i) with (i^2) ?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html - ^ is BITWISE OR

Comment: oops! what is the power sign then ?

Comment: You could use `Math.Pow` too but `i*i` is way more efficient and you don't have to cast to `int` from `double`

Answer (score 1):

The second part of a for loop is a continuation condition. In your case, your continuation condition is `i > 0 && i % 2 != 0`.

For n = 5, the first i is 4, and 4 % 2 is 0. Your continuation condition is not met, and this is why your for loop exits before it begins.

Try

```
    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            iResult = iResult + i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the condition in the for is false, the loop exits.

So for 5, `i=4` and `i % 2 != 0` is false, so the loop isn't accessed at all.

Try this instead:

```
for(i=((n-1)%2==0?n-2:n-1 ; i>0; i=i-2)
{   
     i > 0 && i % 2 != 0; 
}
```

Note that by reducing 2 from `i` at each step, you don't have to check parity on every loop.

Answer (score 0):

First you are setting i as n-1, so it would be 4 if n is 5, then your condition on the for loop states that i must be odd, which 4 is not, so it doesn't even do one loop. Try this:

```
public static int sumOfOddLessThan(int n)
{
    int iResult = 0;
    for(int i = n-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0) iResult += i;
    }
    return iResult;
}
```